# Laravel Optional Route Parameters

Tags: laravel, routes

```
Route::get('dashboard/{path?}', function($path= null)
{
    return $path;
});
```

yeah that makes sense

what if url is

`dashboard/movies/funny/../..`

got `NotFoundHttpException`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per default a route parameter cannot contain any slashes, because multiple route parameters or segments are separated by slashes.

If you have a finite number of path levels you could do this:

```
Route::get('dashboard/{path1?}/{path2?}/{path3?}', function($path1 = null, $path2 = null, $path3 = null)
```

However this isn't very elegant nor dynamic and your example suggests there can be many path levels. You can use a where constraint to allow slashes in the route parameter. So this route will basically catch everything that starts with `dashboard`

```
Route::get('dashboard/{path?}', function($path= null){
    return $path;
})->where('path', '(.*)');
```