# prev and next product links on Product page

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have product catalog with 4 subcategory levels

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/products/{level2?}/{level3?}/{level4?}',   'ProductController@showIndex');
Route::get('/products/{level2?}/{level2prod?}/{level3?}/{level3prod?}/{level4?}/{level4prod?}',     'ProductController@showProduct');
```

First route is showing categories with corresponding products, which are children to current category.
Between Product and Category models there is ManytoMany relationship **$this->belongsToMany**. And I have category_product pivot table.

showProduct function in ProductController receives **$request** and I extract last 2 segments out of **$request->path()**.
Last path segment is equal to current product sef - this is the most important info to load product page. Previous path segment is equal to parent category sef. This is needed to know under which category we are located now. Because one product could belong to many categories and we don't know how current product page was loaded.
In this case I use **$category** to load breadcrumbs like that

```
Home > Products > Category level 2 > Category level3 > Category level4
```

```
    public function showProduct(Request $request) {
        $parent = '';
        $categorysef = '';
        // we need only last part of uri after last slash
        if ( strrpos($request->path(), '/') !== false ) {
            $sef = substr($request->path(), strrpos($request->path(), '/') + 1);
            $parent = substr($request->path(), 0, strrpos($request->path(), '/') );
            if ( strrpos($parent, '/') !== false ) {
                $categorysef = substr($parent, strrpos($parent, '/') + 1);
            }
            else {$categorysef = $parent;}
        } else {
            $sef = $request->path();
        }

        $item     = Product::whereSef($sef)->firstorfail();
        $previous = Product::where('id', '<', $item->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
        $next     = Product::where('id', '>', $item->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->first();
        $category = Category::whereSef($categorysef)->firstorfail();

        return view('product.item')
                    ->withItem($item)
                    ->withPrevious($previous)
                    ->withNext($next)
                    ->withCategory($category);
    }
```

One thing I cannot understand is how to filter **$previous** and **$next** to contain only values belongsTo current category.

Comment: You can't chain multiple optional URL parameters... This is invalid: `{level2?}/{level2prod?}/{level3?}/{level3prod?}/{level4?}/{level4prod?}`. You'd physically have to put `null` in the URL to achieve this, like `/null/null/example/level3`, otherwise `/example/level3` would, to you, map to level3, but the the program would map to level2.

Comment: This is not the point of my question, but anyway if this invalid then why it works?

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer. It's invalid in the sense that as soon as you change the order of params/omit a param, you'll get unexpected results. If you try to navigate to a URL that omits `level2`, and has 2 params, one for level3 and level4, you'll navigate to a route that is handled by level2 and level3.

Comment: I agree, but the only case how you can navigate to route like you suggest is if you manually delete level2 from URL. Because my category logic and routes do not allow to omit parent category. My Category model based on Nestedset. Every node has parent and child relations and it is very comfortable for catalog trees. Finally I tested my catalog. It works well.

Comment: Actually today I found more elegant way for unlimited routes in product catalog here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407827/how-to-declare-unlimited-parameters-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!

```
@if ( !empty($previous) and in_array( $category->id, $previous->category->pluck('id')->toArray()) )
   <li><a href="{{ $previous->sef }}">← Prev</a></li>
@endif
```

Same code for next link.